# "zenith" for a line graph?

Tags: word-choice, mathematics

I have a line graph which illustrates beef consumption. Beef sales peaked at 200 grams per person per day in 1986.

Can I say that "The zenith of beef sales came in 1986, when they reached the highest point of/at 200 grams per person per day"?

Comment: Zenith is typically used more in the sense of culmination, something becoming the best that it can be, grand scale.  It isn't normally applied to a peak in a measure on a chart.

Comment: [*acme, apex, apogee, capstone, climax, crescendo, crest, crown, culmination, head, height, high noon, high-water mark, meridian, ne plus ultra, noon, noontime, **peak,...***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/zenith)

Comment: @fixer1234 but it would be applied to the culmination of beef consumption itself, as illustrated by the chart.

Comment: OP: The first half of your sentence is correct but the word "zenith" is describing the consumption itself and not the graph. The __second half__ of your sentence is grammatically incorrect: "beef sales" is singular, not plural, and it's not "the highest point of/at 200 g/person/day". It's the highest point of consumption, which you'd express as "when it reached its high(est) point of 200 grams per person per day"; "when it reached its maximum at 200 grams per person per day"; "when it reached a high point of 200 grams per person per day"; etc.

Comment: @lly, beef consumption is just a statistic.  It's not like beef achieved greatness; its finest hour being that moment.  "Zenith" wouldn't typically be applied to that.  For that matter, nobody uses the word zenith for anything anymore, at least since the last usage was to refer to a brand of household electronics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper term is: **Peak** [**<sub>Oxford Dictionary</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/peak)

In line-graph, the highest point is called: **Peak**.

**"The peak of beef sales was in 1986, when it reached: 200 grams per person per day"**

---

## Peak

> A point in a curve or on a graph, or a value of a physical quantity, **higher than those around it**.
>
> > ***Usage***: "a slight increase in velocity provides a second **peak** on the general velocity curve."
> >
> > ***Usage***: "When the data is returned to Earth, the measurements are displayed in graphs as **peaks**, with the most abundant mineral boasting the tallest peak."

Answer (score 0):

**zenith**

> figurative. The highest or **best point** (of something); the time or
>   period at which something is at its best, most successful, most
>   powerful, etc.; an acme, a climax. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/232785?redirectedFrom=zenith#eid)

and

> literary: the time when someone or **something** is most successful or effective  [macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/zenith)

Can one use such when describing a sales peak from any visual reference, yes.  There are many good synonyms too. Consider your audience.